# How to query created_at column in postgresql using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I've try a lot and search a lot about this but couldn't find the answer.
Here the code

```
@now = Date.current
@x = User.where("created_at LIKE ?", "#{@now.to_s}%")
```

But it give me this error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ unknown)
```

please help me out

Comment: Maybe you can try `arel_table`. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-arel-to-compose-sql-queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it right, if you want to match rows that have the date part of `created_at` against the current date, try this one

```
User.where('DATE(created_at) = ?', Date.current)
```

Comment: `LIKE` is an operator for strings, not timestamps, like `created_at` is :)

Comment: So, it just comparing the date right? not the timestamp

Comment: Just the date. That's what I got from your question.